# Disparity in options available in Web Deploy 2.0 on two matching servers

Tags: iis-7.5, webdeploy

IIS 7.5 is installed on two servers (both Windows Server 2008 R2) with Web Deploy 2.0 installed (to enable me to Publish from Visual Studio 2010.)  Publishing straight from VS requires the Web Management Service be running on the server.  I've been publishing to the first server for months, no problem.  The second server has just been spun up (not by me) but as far as I can tell has all the same versions of components (OS, IIS, Web Deploy).  However, on the second server the Web Management Service isn't installed.  There's a key difference:

Web Deploy 2.0 options available on the first server:
[image: Web Deploy 2.0 options available on the first server]

Web Deploy 2.0 options available on the second server:
[image: Web Deploy 2.0 options available on the second server]

Why is there a difference between the two?

(Follow-up: I tried the Web Deploy 3.0 installer and encountered the exact same dialog as the second server, above, except that it said "3.0" instead of "2.0".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify the proper IIS roles are installed on your new server. In the Server Manager console, under Web Server (IIS), verify the following roles are installed:

- Management Tools

  - IIS Management Console
  - IIS Management Scripts and Tools
  - Management Service

Then try re-running your Web Deploy installer. I think you'll find you get the options you desire.